# Group multiple similar item under one common name SQL

Tags: sql, excel-formula, case

I have a following situation where I do grouping in Excel, but I want to do same thing in MS SQL Server. I tried with `case` statement but couldn't do it.

Thanks in advance!

Excel formula that i use to group the city by country:

[image]

Comment: Can you copy/paste instead of taking screen shot of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LEFT() function with CASE expression like this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(t.City,3) = 'DAL' then 'USA'
            WHEN LEFT(t.City,3) = 'LON' then 'ENDLAND'
            .............
            END as Country
FROM YourTable
```